# How to access an array that contains another type of array in kotlin

Tags: arrays, loops, kotlin, for-loop, indexing

Here, I have an array of `FloatArray` and an array of `IntArray` namely `vertices` and `indices` respectively. Another one is an array of `FloatArray` called `partial_vbo` initialized with null values with the size of 36(i.e 36 elements of `Float` can fit in).

**How do I iterate the `indices`, so that I could use its element as an index to the `vertices` which then being copied to the variable `partial_vbo`.**

For example, the first element of `indices` is `[0,2,3]` which is an array. Then, I iterate this array, the first element is 0, so 0 is passed to `vertices` like so `vertices[0]`, so then it will give me the object of `[-1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f]` in one go, meaning one array of float not only one float.
I tried to print the output using two techniques, but it outputs differently than I thought it would.

```
    fun main(){

    val vertices= arrayOf
    (
        floatArrayOf(-1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f), floatArrayOf(1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f), 
        floatArrayOf(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f),floatArrayOf(-1.0f,1.0f,1.0f),
        floatArrayOf(-1.0f,1.0f,-1.0f), floatArrayOf(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f), 
        floatArrayOf(1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f), floatArrayOf(1.0f,1.0f,-1.0f)
    )
    val indices=arrayOf(
        intArrayOf(0,2,3), intArrayOf(0,1,2), intArrayOf(1,7,2), intArrayOf(1,6,7),
        intArrayOf(6,5,4), intArrayOf(4,7,6), intArrayOf(3,4,5), intArrayOf(3,5,0),
        intArrayOf(3,7,4), intArrayOf(3,2,7), intArrayOf(0,6,1), intArrayOf(0,5,6)
    )
    var partial_vbo= arrayOfNulls<FloatArray>(36)

    
    for( i in vertices.indices){
        for(j in indices.indices){
            for( k in 0..2){
                println(vertices[indices[j][k]][k])
            }
        }
    }
    //It prints 96 objects of type `FloatArray`, actually it is of type 
    //`Float` line by 
    //line, like -1.0,1.0, etc. I summarize this for you so that it is 
    //easier for us.
    //It seems like it jumps from the first array, then into the second   
    //array while mantaining the first element.
    // its like vertices[i][0], like i++ or something like this

    for(i in vertices){
        for(j in indices){
            for(k in 0..2)
                println(i[j[k]])
        }
    }
    //if i try to access the element using this syntax, i got exception
    // Index 3 out of bounds for length 3


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you want to use the indices subarrays consecutively to lookup entries in vertices and the result would end in partial_vbo:

```
val partial_vbo = indices
  .flatMap { it.toList() }
  .map { vertices[it] }
```

Edit:

The above use of [flatMap](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-transformations.html#flatten) could be replaced in a imperative way like this:

```
val indicesFlatMapped = mutableListOf<Int>()

for (subIndices in indices) {
  indicesFlatMapped.addAll(subIndices.toList())
}
```

The second step with [map](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-transformations.html#map) does roughly the following:

```
val partial_vbo = arrayOfNulls<FloatArray>(36)

for ((index, int) in indicesFlatMapped.withIndex()) {
  partial_vbo[index] = vertices[int]
}
```

See also: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collections-overview.html
and: https://play.kotlinlang.org/byExample/05_Collections/01_List

Comment: wow, this one works well, I have heard about this kind of functions nowadays but not quite sure what it is actually. Is this called higher order function, or lambda function, or maybe function with template parameters, usually with the predicate parameters to be supplied to the function. Usually when i press '.' , then scroll down what function can I use, and usually one of these pop up that requires me to supply the `predicate`. I usually ignore these kind of function, because I am not sure how it works. But, here it is it helps a lot.

Comment: @beginner Added 'translations' to equivalent imperative code.